# AWS to SQL pandas AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, amazon-web-services

I am trying to move a CSV data from a AWS bucket to a SQL Server using pandas to read the file, but when i try to insert the data to SQL Server I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'user_id'. There is indeed a column named user_id on the CSV file.

Thats the code im using

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc



cxnsql = pyodbc.connect('DSN=BD-RJ-HMG;DATABASE=AnalyticsPMais;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
s3c = boto3.client('s3')
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
date = datetime.strftime(yesterday, '%Y-%m-%d')
file='s3://poliedro-prod-relatorios/consumptions-'+date+'.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)

cursor = cxnsql.cursor()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO AnalyticsPMais.dbo.LivroDigital (user_id,livro_id,date) values(?,?,?)", row.user_id, row.livro_id, row.date)
cxnsql.commit()
cursor.close()
```

What is going on?

Comment: Can you check if there is no extra space or any character in the columns name `user_id`?

Comment: Tnx marcin! Ive already solved the problem. It was a wrong delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Each `row` in your for loop is a pandas `Series` object. To select an element in a `Series` object by its index, use [`Series.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html)

For example, if you want the `user_id`, use

```
row.loc['user_id']
```

Comment: I tried in this way but it returned this error: Traceback (most recent call last):

    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'user_id'